# TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument (LinkedList)

Tags: python, data-structures

The problem I have is with my linked list implementation, it simply does not want to recognize my argument. Let me show you the code to illustrate what I mean:

```
class Node:
        def __init__(self, element:int):
            self.element = element
            
        element:int = 0
        nextNode = None

class LinkedList:
    head:Node = None
        
    def insert(self, element:int):
        if self.head == None:
            currentNode = Node.__init__(element)
            self.head = currentNode
        else:
            currentNode = self.head
            while currentNode.nextNode != None:
                currentNode = currentNode.nextNode
            newNode = Node.__init__(element)
            currentNode.nextNode = newNode 
    
    def prettyPrint(self):
        currentNode = self.head
        
        print("Current Linked List\n")
        while currentNode.nextNode != None:
            print(currentNode.element+" ---> ")
            currentNode = currentNode.nextNode
        
                
            

def main():
    Linkedlist = LinkedList()
    Linkedlist.insert(1)
    Linkedlist.insert(9)
    Linkedlist.insert(2)
    Linkedlist.insert(18)
    Linkedlist.insert(5)
    Linkedlist.insert(8)
    Linkedlist.prettyPrint()
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error happens in the insert method at

> currentNode = Node.**init**(element)

I'm new to Python and so any help is appreciated.

Comment: replace ```currentNode = Node.__init__(element)``` with  ```currentNode = Node(element)```. We don't call ```__init__```, while creating object, we just call class, and it will automatically call ```__init__``` for us.

Comment: Also, may I ask why ```element:int = 0
        nextNode = None``` are outside of the ```__init__``` and why is ```element:int = 0``` even there?

Comment: @BhusalC_Bipin aaaaaah ty for the help! Didn't realize that's how it worked in python. Oh and for the second comment, those are class variables, I should probably put them before the method. I wanted to initialize the element variable so that it is recognized as a int variable from the get go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code with two small fixes:

1. Construct a `Node` by calling `Node(element)`
2. in `print` either separate arguments with a `,` or use `end="something"` to tell `print` to put a `"something"` at the end of the output.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, element: int):
        self.element = element

    element: int = 0
    nextNode = None


class LinkedList:
    head: Node = None

    def insert(self, element: int):
        if self.head == None:
            currentNode = Node(element)
            self.head = currentNode
        else:
            currentNode = self.head
            while currentNode.nextNode != None:
                currentNode = currentNode.nextNode
            newNode = Node(element)
            currentNode.nextNode = newNode

    def prettyPrint(self):
        currentNode = self.head

        print("Current Linked List\n")
        while currentNode.nextNode != None:
            print(currentNode.element, end=" ---> ")
            currentNode = currentNode.nextNode


def main():
    Linkedlist = LinkedList()
    Linkedlist.insert(1)
    Linkedlist.insert(9)
    Linkedlist.insert(2)
    Linkedlist.insert(18)
    Linkedlist.insert(5)
    Linkedlist.insert(8)
    Linkedlist.prettyPrint()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Have fun learning python ;)

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaah ty very much, I come from java so I thought I could do something similar here!

Comment: https://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, replace `currentNode = Node.__init__(element)` with  `currentNode = Node(element)`.

Also, I would recommend to change your `Node` class to something like this.

```py
class Node:
        def __init__(self, element:int):
            self.element = element
            self.nextNode = None
```

**Furthermore** there are another issues in your `prettyPrint()` method.

First, you will get `TypeError` because of line, `print(currentNode.element+" ---> ")`.

Second, you are not printing the last element of the linked list. So, add `print(currentNode.element)` after the `while loop`.

So, I would change it to something like this to get your desired output.

```py
def prettyPrint(self):
        currentNode = self.head
    
        print("Current Linked List\n")
        while currentNode.nextNode != None:
            print(currentNode.element, end=' ---> ')
            currentNode = currentNode.nextNode
        print(currentNode.element)
```